# How to get the RAM used by a batch file within the same batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file that when run displays the the memory(RAM) used by it in its window's title. I have tried the following code using wmic command but its not working

```
:START
cls
set /A exe_count=%exe_count%+1
set /A mem_usage="wmic process where name='kill_tasks.bat' get WorkingSetSize | findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*"" 
title task kill -- execution count: %exe_count%, mem: %mem_usage%
<Other codes>
SLEEP 30
GOTO START
```

When the wmic command is executed it shows an error message:

> missing operator

And the title of the window would be

> task kill -- execution count: 1, mem: 0

If I run the wmic command seperately in a new command prompt window after the batch file has began to run it shows the error:

> No Instance(s) Available.

Comment: It seems like a pointless exercise to determine that data within the file itself. As soon as you begin to check it will raise the value, your value will then reflect the checking mechanism and not the batch files actual process.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example of how the WMIC will not provide you with an accurate figure, *or possibly one you can trust*, take a look at the following example script:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    "WMIC Process Where (Name='cmd.exe') Get CommandLine, WorkingSetSize|Find /I %0"
') Do For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%B In ("%%A") Do For %%C In (%%B) Do Echo( [%%C]
Timeout -1
```

You will notice that there are two outputs, one from the initial invokation of the script and another from the WMIC command part. My initial idea was that the first figure would be the smaller of the two and therefore the one you require. Unfortunately though this figure isn't always smaller and therfore may not be the one you require.

It's also worth bearing in mind that built-in commands such as find.exe and timeout.exe will each probably register a different figure external of the batch file and therefore not be included in either of those returned figures.

**Edit**

Below is a version which ignores the advice above and saves the Working Set Size to `%WSS%`.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "WSS="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    "WMIC Process Where (Name='cmd.exe') Get CommandLine, WorkingSetSize|Find /I %0"
') Do For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%B In ("%%A") Do For %%C In (%%B
) Do If Not Defined WSS Set "WSS=%%C"
Echo( [%WSS%]
Timeout -1
```